# Serial.print() truncates data when reading with QSerialPort

Tags: qt, arduino, serial-port

I am trying to write a simple integer value from an Arduino Mega 2560 to a Qt Application. Baudrate is set to 9600 and `Serial.read()` works fine when I send data through an open port with `serial->write(some_data);` from Qt Application.

```
digitalWrite(SS, LOW);
if (Serial.available() == 2) {
  response1 = SPI.transfer(Serial.read());
  response2 = SPI.transfer(Serial.read());
}
digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
```

The above code works fine. I read another by before and had to add `delay(3)` to make this work. Now I want to send back the response

```
Serial.print((response2 << 8 ) | (response1 & 0xFF));
```

But there are always truncated digits. I know from the logic analyzer that the response is e.g. `8193` so with `QByteArray b = serial->readAll();` I get results like `8`, `81`, `819`, and sometimes `8193`. I.e.: always the last digits are truncated randomly. I assume that this is also a timing issue but I could not find a fix for this.

Comment: readAll() just returns the bytes that have been received so far.  On a fast PC that is usually just 1 or 2 bytes.  Increasing the baudrate is not a fix, you'll get more bytes but exactly how many is never a guarantee.  Smart way to do this is to send a '\n' as well so you can use readLine() in your Qt code.  Now it works the same way it does in your Arduino and never goes wrong.

Comment: I started off with `readLine()` in the Qt code and `Serial.println()` in the Arduino code and experienced the same behaviour. I will double check if i did not accidentally miss anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone facing the same issue: Changing the Baudrate from 9600 to 112500 fixed this.